# How to create crs for leaflet using pro4js

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geometry, gis, proj4js

I am a newbie to leaflet, and need an crs function sample to create an system that
can change the coordinate system from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:3826.
The basic library for coordinate I hope to use is proj4js, and I have the sample code as
following:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:3826', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs');;
proj4.defs("GOOGLE", "EPSG:3857");
var coord = proj4("EPSG:3826", "GOOGLE", [longitude, latitude]);
```

However, to create crs for leaflet need more to define, is there any good sample to refer for me to write a library to make that? Any instruction is highly appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can get the proj4js definition for EPSG:3857 from https://epsg.io/3857 – that should be enough: `proj4.defs("EPSG:3857","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs");`

Comment: I can not figure out the crs function for leaflet via these two proj4.defs(). The codes I hope to create seems like this : var map = new L.Map('map', {crs: crs, crossOrigin: true}); and crs function obj is like var crs = .....some definition for cooridate.